# How to calculate means from a column in a list of lists?

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have generated a list of 203 single data tables in form of a list. I used sapply to create it and it looks something like this:[image]

In each of the tables I would like to select the **slope_CC** value (it duplicated it so its the same value a few times). I calculate the mean of them instead of selecting one of them because it's easier. The goal is to have all the means in one new data table. The tables have different row numbers.

```
First_table <- slope_list$selected0.csv

get_means_fun <- function(First_table){
  N <- First_table[["slope_CC"]]
  mean <- mean(N)
  return(data.frame(mean))
}

list_select <- lst(pattern=".csv", slope_list)
get_means <- lapply(list_select, get_means_fun)
```

Is `lapply()` the best way to do this?
I get this error: **Error in First_table[["slope_CC"]] : subscript out of bounds** even though when I run the same line individually it works.

Comment: Try `First_table["slope_CC"]` in your function!

Comment: See how some of your list objects (e.g., selected1.csv) are not data.frames, but rather a logical [1]? Those will fail in the function, as they obviously do not have your desired column. You need to either remove those beforehand, or have a way to skip them in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a dummy example of what I think you are looking for. My main tweak is that instead of taking the mean, which requires R to sum each element and then divide by length, I simply grab the first value.

```r
# example data
list_select <- list(table1 = head(mtcars),
                    table2 = FALSE,
                    table3 = tail(mtcars))

# grab the first value of column "wt". switch this for your column
# this checks to see if it is a data.frame, if not, return NA
# you can change this to return a NULL, or whatever you would like.
get_value_function <- function(the_table) {
  if (is.data.frame(the_table)) the_table[["wt"]][1] else NA
}

# returns a list
lapply(list_select, get_value_function)
# $table1
# [1] 2.62
# 
# $table2
# [1] NA
# 
# $table3
# [1] 2.14

# returns a vector
sapply(list_select, get_value_function)
# table1 table2 table3 
# 2.62     NA   2.14
```

I also like to do stuff like this in `purrr`. It saves having to create the function ahead of time.

```r
library(purrr)

# returns a list like lapply
map(list_select, ~ if (is.data.frame(.x)) .x[["wt"]][1] else NA)

# returns a vector sapply
map_dbl(list_select, ~ if (is.data.frame(.x)) .x[["wt"]][1] else NA)
```

Another approach could be to remove the list elements which are not data.frames ahead of time. A really simple way, again with `purrr`, is to use `keep`.

```r
list_select %>% 
  keep(is.data.frame) %>% 
  map_dbl(~ .x[["wt"]][1])

# table1 table3 
# 2.62   2.14
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked with is.data.table. However, I think these outputs are a bit complicated for further use. I'm not so used to work with these lists, instead of normal data frames.